# how to validate url using gevent

Tags: python, rabbitmq, gevent

I have one million urls to be validated.
some of them is unreachable from my country,and some are invalid,I want to validate all the urls.
I use python to do that,and use gevent to accelerate the speed,but I'm new to gevent,some seem didn't work.
my code is following:

```
import gevent
import gevent.monkey
import urllib2
from gevent.pool import Pool
from gevent import Timeout
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
p = Pool(10)

seconds = 10

#timeout = Timeout(seconds)
#timeout.start()
#timer = Timeout(3).start()

def down(url):
    urllib2.urlopen(url)


def wait():
    while True:
        gevent.sleep(0)
        print 'hi'
        with Timeout(5,False):
            p.spawn(down,'http://www.twitter.com')
        print '---------------------------------'
wait()
```

twitter is unreachable from my country,the output is:

```
hi
---------------------------------
hi
---------------------------------
hi
```

and it didn't tell timeout after 5 seconds,what's wrong with my code?

and I wonder to know how to add a new task to gevent when running.

I want to validate all my urls in distribution,so I read url from my database and send the url to a message queue,a lot receivers receive message from the message and then validate the url.

my message is rabbitmq.

I just know if I have a 10 urls,I can use gevent like:

```
for x in xrange(10)
    tasks.append(gevent.spawn(validate,url))
gevent.joinall(tasks)
```

but in my situation,I just read one message and then spawn a greenlet,and if a url is unreachable,it will block the message until the greenlet is finished.

so how can I do some async way to validate my urls?
such as I always read the url back and spawn greenlet without blocking.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your IO/"waiting" code with the `with Timeout()`. Right now, you're wrapping the `gevent.spawn()`/`pool.spawn()` call, which isn't right. In this case, the IO code you want to timeout on is `urllib2.urlopen(url)`.

Code of this nature would typically look something like this:

```
validated = []
urls = ["http://a.com", "http://b.com"]

def down(url):
    with Timeout(5, False):
        urllib2.urlopen(url)
        validated.append(url)

pool = gevent.Pool(10)
for url in urls:
    pool.spawn(down, url)
pool.join() #you didn't call pool.join() in the original code because you have a wait loop already, which is okay
print "Valid URLs are: %s" % ", ".join(validated)
```

You can keep your infinite `while True` loop, and in there grab incoming URLs from your database/queue. That's probably what you want. I'm just giving an example of what I would do to check a pre-set list of URLs I want to verify.

In that case, your error is that you wrapped `pool.spawn()` with the `with Timeout()`. The act of just spawning a greenlet will happen almost instantly, so adding a timeout around that will do nothing. That is why you aren't seeing a timeout. You need to wrap the `urllib2.urlopen()` call with the `Timeout()` context.

Also, if you're just checking for timeouts, this works fine. You may want to check if the request returned an HTTP `200` code though, in which case you should be checking `urllib2.urlopen(url).getcode()`.